# Footer in Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-tabactivity, android-tabbed-activity

I am using **Tabbed Activity** and I have three tabs with corresponding fragments. Now I want to dispay a footer that displays on every fragment when I change the Tab. Is this possible?? Please give me an simple example

Comment: You can do it by two methods by adding the footer in the main Activity and change the data on tab change . Second is add the footer in each fragment ..

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I am new to android, can you show how to achieved through by main Activity?? any example or reff link?

Comment: please post your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footer layout u will paste into **Tabbed activity layout** below tab host xml

like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TabHost>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

After that change view in footer based on tab selection using like this

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String s) {
                //Add view into footer or hide 
            }
        });
```